# SQL Impala create partitioned table from a view

Tags: sql, partitioning, impala, create-table

I am interested in turning a view into a table, but I want the table to be partitioned wrt to one variable:
My query is:

CREATE TABLE table_test AS (
SELECT
*
FROM view_test

And I want to have the table partitioned by the variable "time-period".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly like this

```
CREATE TABLE table_test
PARTITIONED BY (time_period)
as 
SELECT col1,col2,
time_period -- Pls make sure this partition column as the last column in SELECT.
FROM  schema.view_test;
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) It works. Can I also pre-order these partitioned rows somehow?

Comment: pre order in the sense ? Store the data in ordered manner so that fetch is faster? its not possible. Impala will create separate physical folder to store partitions so its immaterial if you sort the data while insert into/creating table.